# Cmake can find boost but not boost core

Tags: boost, cmake

I have installed the `libboost-all-dev` packaged on Ubuntu.

Cmake 3.10.2 can find boost but not "`boost_core`".

When I change the find package line to:

> `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS core)`

Then it complains that it can't find "`boost_core`".

I actually just need `boost/iterator`...

How to make cmake find that?

Thanks.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test_boost_iterator)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_definitions( "-DHAS_BOOST" )

add_executable(test_boost_iterator main.cpp)
```

Success message (before replacing the `find_package` line):

```
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Error message (after replacing the `find_package` line)

```
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_core

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

Comment: In your code snippet you didn't specify `COMPONENTS` for `find_package`.

Comment: Yea. That works before I change the `find_package` line to `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS core)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no such a boost library `core`. You can check if a library should be linked [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries).
And `Boost.Iterator` is a header-only library, so you don't need to link anything. Just include `<boost/iterator/...>`. If you can't include, check whether these includes actually exist in your local boost distro.

I checked it for `boost::counting_iterator<int>` and all works well for me.

Comment: This works without using cmake. But boost can be in non-standard locations, especially for installation without admin rights.

Comment: If it is in non-standard location, specify it as custom include directory. I don't think FindBoost will find it, if it is located at some esoteric place. Can you tell what your problem is? Why should you change `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)`?